# How do I reset the cached data of my singleton class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, singleton

In my iOS application I am creating a singleton classs like follow, and the same class has some properties, so when I set some values to the properties all the data will be cached to memory, now how do I reset the singleton object ?

how do I do some thing like this [Model sharedInstance] = nil ?

```
Model.m

    + (instancetype)sharedInstance
    {
        static Model *objModel = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t predicate;
        dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
            objModel = [[Model alloc]init];
        });
        return objModel;
    }
```

Comment: You can create a `+(void)reset` method that will do for each property [Model sharedInstance].property = nil, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. its simply what a singleton is. An entity that is initialised once. If you want to "re-instantiate" then its not a singleton pattern anymore. Probably you are more inclined in using global variables?

However, you can clear the properties of a singleton something like this: `[Object instance].myMutableProperty = nil;`

quoting [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern): `In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.`